# How can I improve security for Weaviate in local environment?

Tags: security, openai-api, gpt-3, weaviate, vector-database

I'm currently setting up Weaviate, the open-source, GraphQL and RESTful API-based knowledge graph, on my local environment. Although it's a local setup, I would like to ensure robust security measures are applied to protect it from any potential threats.

The specifics for my setup are:

Operating System: ubuntu 22.04
Weaviate Version: v1.19
Here is my current configuration: (Please replace this line with your existing configuration details)

What are the best practices to enhance security in this scenario? Any kind of suggestions regarding improving the security like encrypting data at rest, securing communication with SSL/TLS, protecting APIs with authentication layers and the ways to implement them would be really appreciated.

I've looked around but couldn't quite find what I was looking for, so any guidance or resources would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for any help!

I tried setting up API authentication